# display user profile as part of my plugin page in moodle

Tags: plugins, moodle, moodle-api

I'm creating a moodle local plugin and I need to display the current user's profile page as part of my page and add my data after that.
is there any API that give me the profile page (with all additional fields) so I will be able to show it in my page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use global variable $USER. You will find all the records of current logged in user in $USER and display according to your requirement.